# Is it possible to add reactive pie charts on the world map using D3.js

Tags: javascript, matplotlib, d3.js, plotly.js

I am making a component in Vue.js and I aim to make a reactive component as shown in the image. I don't know how D3.js works, if it is possible to achieve using D3.js then I will learn. [image: desired component look]

My requirement is:

1. When I click on any of the pie in the pie chart, the corresponding data related to that should be shown in different SVG. Is it possible to implement using D3.js

If this is possible with any other open-source library, please feel free to mention it.

thankyou

Comment: Yes, it's pretty straightforward - you can draw pie charts as usual tweaking only where they are centered, drawing them over top of a map.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible with d3.